# Wifi settings and networks not being shown on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless

I recently switched over to ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Windows 10. No WiFi networks or settings are being shown in networks in system settings. I tried tried the lspci -nn command and found that I have no network controller listed. What should I do? My WiFi connection worked fine on Windows.

Comment: post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 shows no output

Comment: sudo lshw -C network shows only my ethernet adapter. Wired connections working fine

Comment: Is this a new Ubuntu installation of 16.04? As Pilot suggested run the following lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 once this is done we can see which chipset your machine is using and you will be able to install the correct wireless drivers needed to get your machine connected.  You can also view the following post it may have important information that may help with this isses. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: The problem turned out to be a hardware issue with my Wifi Card. Thanks for taking the time to go through my question!